# How can i access categories->tablet->desc from json file?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
"categories":{
    "tablet":{
        "image":"1.png",
        "desc" : "Tablet Description",
         "button": "SHOP NOW!"   
    },
    "laptop":{
        "image":"1.png",
        "desc" : "Laptop Description",
         "button": "SHOP NOW!" 
    },
    "monitor":{
        "image":"1.png",
        "desc" : "Monitor Description",
         "button": "SHOP NOW!" 
    }
}
```

I am trying to use below code but unable to get it-

```
productList = JSON.parse("demo.json");

//console.log(productList.categories.tablet.desc);
for (category in productList.categories) {
      console.log(category.desc);
}
```

But outside loop when i use this line its showing correctly.

```
console.log(productList.categories.tablet.desc);
```

Comment: Try category.tablet.desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because, in your for loop you get a key which corresponds to the direct child present in categories, and your `desc` property is grand child of categories so what you are trying to do is :

```
categories.desc // desc property is not present in categoies.
```

Try the following:

```js
var productList = {"categories": {"tablet":{"image":"1.png","desc":"Tablet Description","button":"SHOP NOW!"},"laptop":{"image":"1.png","desc":"Laptop Description","button":"SHOP NOW!"},"monitor":{"image":"1.png","desc":"Monitor Description","button":"SHOP NOW!"}}};

for(category in productList.categories){
  console.log(productList.categories[category].desc);
}
```

Comment: can you explain how to use the productList object instead of using the json directly? the original post suggests they are parsing the JSON, not that they have the JSON directly

Comment: @AshleshSortee happy to help you:-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (category in productList.categories) {
      console.log(productList.categories[category].desc);
}
```

Category doesn't give you the object; it gives you the key to access productList.categories with.